# How can I return the selected ID from the view it always returns id 1 to Flask route

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, jinja2

I have a table that is the result of a Sqlite3 search and it is displayed in a view disp.html. It displays the record ID and the meta-data for each record in the database.  When I select the record id from the table it should display the detailed data for the selected record ID. But what is happening is that regardless of the record ID selected I always get the first ID returned to the route.

How do I get the view to return the selected ID to the route?

disp.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block maindisplay %}
    <form action="/display" method="post">
        <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Data ID</th>
                    <th>Data One</th>
                    <th>Data Two</th>
                    <th>Data Three</th>
                    <th>Data Four</th>
                    <th>Data Five</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for data in display_data %}
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="hidden" name="pid" value='{{ data["ID"] }}'><button btn class="formatButton">{{ data["IDo"] }}</button></td>
                        <td>{{ data["one"] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ data["two"] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ data["three"] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ data["four"] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ data["five"] }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Output of the view

```
ID    Data One    Data Two    Data Three    Data Four    Data Five
1     One1        Two1        Three1        Four1        Five1
2     One2        Two2        Three2        Four2        Five2
3     One3        Two3        Three3        Four3        Five3
```

Route

```
@app.route("/display", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def list_data():
    if request.method == "POST":
        dataZero=request.form.get("pid")
        ...
        return render_template("pdisplay.html", dataZero=dataZero)
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the <input> elements have the same **name** attribute; only one value is submitted with the form, assume the first one.

One solution would be to make the type attribute of [<input> elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) "submit" instead of "hidden". There would be no need for the buttons.

Another solution would be to give each [<button> element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) a name ("pid") and a value; the value from the clicked button is submitted with the form. There would be no need for the hidden <input> elements.

In either case, all the elements can share the same name attribute because the form action is triggered on the "click" and the value submitted will be from the element that is "clicked".

Comment: Thank you for your reply. - 

Can you elaborate on the "give each element a name".  Are you suggesting a unique name for each button?  I don't know how many entries will eventually be in the database so I am not sure how provide a unique name for each entry. - 

Although changing the input type from hidden to submit works, it puts a box around the ID which I was trying to avoid.  I will try this method and look up how CSS might be able to eliminate the border.

Comment: I added clarity to the answer (hopefully :). All the button elements can have the same "name" because as soon as a button is clicked the form is submitted with the value from the clicked button. The same is true for input type="submit". In either case the elements can share a name attribute, because the form action is triggered on the click.

Comment: Thank you, I used the button solution and it works perfectly and no borders. Thanks again.